# Elm websocket request origin within a browser

Tags: html, heroku, websocket, request, elm

Lets say I make an elm app; it requests data from a websocket to check the price of bitcoin from say poloniex.com. I compile it to an .html file and  I deploy it to say Heroku or whatever server I like on the backend.

When a user comes to my website and requests that .html file, and is then looking at the bitcoin price from the websocket request, **is the user's IP address making that websocket request or is it the backend's (eg Heroku in this case) IP address making the websocket request?**

I ask because I was considering two different designs. Either have my backend pull the bitcoin price data and then serve that to my users or have the users directly request the price from the source itself (i.e poloniex in this case). The latter would be less headache but won't be possible if all the requests end up coming from the backend and therefore one ip address (they would have request limits)

Edit: Bolded for people who couldn't see where the question was.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Just bolded it. Jesus, people love to down vote here.

Comment: @Jimbo yes, they do - but usually with fairly good reason, for the most part it helps with the quality of the questions - in this case the subject is not explicit and if one person missed the question the odd are high that others will too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the standard Elm Websocket package, [`elm-lang/websocket`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/websocket/1.0.2/WebSocket), the websocket connects with whatever URL you point it at. If you set it up like this:

```
subscriptions model =
    listen "ws://echo.websocket.org" Echo
```

Then the client browser will connect directly with `echo.websocket.org`. The target of that websocket connection will likely see your application as a referrer, but its connection will be with the IP of the user's browser that is acting as the client.

If you instead want your backend server application to act as a proxy, you would use that URL in `listen`

```
subscriptions model =
    listen "ws://myapp.com" ...
```

Comment: So the target will not ban my application as the connection will be to the individual user. The application therefore be seen as "one" user?

Comment: You'll have to refer to the target application's terms of service. If the browser connects directly to poloniex.com, then poloniex.com will see the IP of your user's browser, but will likely see the URL of your Heroku application in a referrer header. Your target server application may have some notion of token authentication for rate limiting (e.g. like working with Google APIs requires an API token)